# How to write async/await in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

In the [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), it says

```
async function foo() { 
    await 1
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
    return Promise.resolve(1).then(() => undefined)
}
```

so what is the eqivalent of

```
async function foo() {
    await genPromise();
}
```

assuming that genPromise() returns another Promise.

Would it be

```
function foo() {
    return Promise.resolve(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})).then(() => undefined)
}
```

Comment: Yes. Kind of (you are missing a `return` though). The engine would probably skip the creation of unused Promise objects.

Comment: Thanks! Just noticed the missing return and added it.

Comment: `async`/`await` *is* vanilla JavaScript since ES8.

Comment: I guess a better way to phrase it is how to write async/await as Promise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so what is the eqivalent of
>
> ```
> async function foo() {
>    await genPromise();
> }
> ```

That code will wait for the promise returned by genPromise to resolve, and then will resolve its own promise to `undefined`. So the equivalent is:

```
function foo() {
  return genPromise().then(() => undefined);
}
```

Comment: If `genPromise` would not return a promise, you'd need a `Promise.resolve(...)` around it

Comment: So Promise.resolve() generated by "async" is gone if the await value returns a new Promise?

Comment: @apcyang Not really. It is used to determine if it's a promise. However, the JS engine may skip creating another Promise object in that case, but that isn't the part you should care about

Comment: Ah ok. So the key idea is it would skip creation of unused Promise like @Jonas Wilms is saying also. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Notice that this will not have equivalent error handling characteristics if `getPromise` synchronously throws an exception

Comment: @Bergi, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @apcyang Just compare the two results with `function getPromise() { throw new Error("oops, not a promise"); }`